# Set HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to set `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type` in ASP.NET. That is a read-only, string property. So you cannot really just assign a string to it. Tried initializing Browser property which is of type HttpBrowserCapabilities, but it has only one constructor and does not take any parameters and browser Type is still null. The reason why I want to be able to set  Type for browser is that my unit test is failing as Type property is null.

Edit per null check comments:
I could definitely modify code to check for null, but that will be just for my unit test as when the requests come from browsers, that value is never null. Hence not quite excited about doing that. But it can be my last resort.

Comment: Seems to me it would be easier to alter the test to account for the possibility of a null browser type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to think about refactoring your code to use [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) instead of relying directly on the concrete type.

By doing so you could simply create a stub object that provides the behavior you want. Eventually implementing your own [HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilitiesbase.aspx) object.

You would then have full control to use your mock types during unit testing. Indeed that is what they were created for.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own browser definition files which ASP.net will then use.   Check out http://forums.asp.net/p/955969/1176101.aspx.

So if you know what browser it's failing on you could setup a browser file for it.  However, I agree that checking for null values makes more sense as it accounts for a lot more possiblities that way.